# Monitor file access count by user

Tags: linux, filesystems, files, linux-audit

I have written a script which is deployed just by putting it in a globally accessible location for all users. I want to log the usage of this script.

Is there a way in Linux to find out how many times a file was read/accessed?
And if possible to determine by who ?

Edit: I do not have the root privileges, and `auditd` isn't an option, since its not already available.

Comment: Usually done using auditd, or similar, I think. E.g. http://xmodulo.com/2013/05/how-to-monitor-file-access-on-linux.html also http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with the default `ext2/3/4` linux file system, I think your only solution is to log the usage of your file into a log file (but people could find that file and modify it.
So my advice would be to use a small web service (`PHP`, `Python` or even `perl` that increment a value in a db so people could not change the value easily).

**Edit 1**:
Well it seems some software could accomplish such a task see the post
[Script to count number of times a file has been accessed](https://superuser.com/q/372587/264697)

**Edit 2**  *(as state by commentators)*:
You can start with a [good tutorial](http://xmodulo.com/2013/05/how-to-monitor-file-access-on-linux.html) on `auditd`  deamon.
And also [search google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=tutorial%20auditd) or [Duck duck go](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=tutorial%20%22auditd%22) for `auditd` which is the name of the deamon you will need.

Comment: @deowood it takes me a 2 minutes search to find this, you could try to make your homework before asking that fast next time. ;-)

Comment: I did my homework, but had no success; probably wrong choice of keywords!